# Скрипт скачивания на хост файл по ссылке

Tags: php, cron

Нужен такой скриптик, чтобы скачивал по ссылочке файл на сам хост. Дело будет происходить по CronTab'у.

Comment: А что у вас не получается?

Comment: Собственно сделать такой скрипт, чтобы скачивал файл... Навыков не хватает.

Comment: Даже о командах таких не слышал. (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если скрипт будет запускаться по крону на сервере, то вполне достаточно использовать [wget](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget). Примеры использования на странице Википедии. Например,

```
wget ftp://login:password@ftp.example.org/some_file.iso
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function downloadFile($filename, $mimetype='application/octet-stream') {
if (!file_exists($filename)) die('Файл не найден');

$from=$to=0; $cr=NULL;

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
    $range=substr($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], '=')+1);
    $from=strtok($range, '-');
    $to=strtok('/'); if ($to>0) $to++;
    if ($to) $to-=$from;
    header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
    $cr='Content-Range: bytes ' . $from . '-' . (($to)?($to . '/' . $to+1):filesize($filename));
} else  header('HTTP/1.1 200 Ok');

$etag=md5($filename);
$etag=substr($etag, 0, 8) . '-' . substr($etag, 8, 7) . '-' . substr($etag, 15, 8);
header('ETag: "' . $etag . '"');

header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Length: ' . (filesize($filename)-$to+$from));
if ($cr) header($cr);

header('Connection: close');
header('Content-Type: ' . $mimetype);
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('r', filemtime($filename)));
$f=fopen($filename, 'r');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filename) . '";');
if ($from) fseek($f, $from, SEEK_SET);
if (!isset($to) or empty($to)) {
    $size=filesize($filename)-$from;
} else {
    $size=$to;
}
$downloaded=0;
while(!feof($f) and !connection_status() and ($downloaded<$size)) {
    echo fread($f, 512000);
    $downloaded+=512000;
    flush();
}
fclose($f);
```

}

Использовать так

```
downloadFile('file/archive.zip', 'application/zip');// Выдаём пользователю файл "file/archive.zip" и указываем MIME-тип
```

[Источник](http://webmastak.com/article.aspx?id=322).

Так пробовали?

```
<?php
$file = 'example.txt';
$newfile = 'example.txt.bak';

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "не удалось скопировать $file...\n";
} 
?>
```

[Источник](http://php.su/functions/?copy)

Comment: Благодарю, побегу проверять)

Comment: Вижу, вы меня немного не так поняли... Нужно не чтобы пользователь мог скачать файл, а чтобы сервер качал файл на себя по посторонней ссылке